# FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: deployment, tomcat7

I am unable to deploy .war on Tomcat 7. It is working fine on one of the servers but not working on the other. Following is the error that I get.

```
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AppAPIs]]
```

Following are the content of catalina.out

> WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AppAPIs]]
>   so no cleanup was performed for that container
>
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp is not bound in this
>   Context   at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:977)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:959)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5470)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:747)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:222)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Jun 25, 2012 7:10:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/data/softwares/appapis/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/AppAPIs/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

PS: I have checked previous solutions but nothing seems to be working out for me. I checked my web.xml but nothings seems to be a problem there.

There are no duplicate jar files in my lib

Comment: Your classpath is mangled. You've got servlet-api.jar in the WEB-INF/lib. What else have you got in there that you don't need?

Comment: This is what I found out, I have servlet-api.jar in my lib. I guess it is creating the conflict at server.  I need servlet-api.jar to compile my project.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a weird problem, but I resolved it by carefully checking web.xml of my project. This same problem occurred when I added 1 wrong servlet config line to web.xml and it disappeared when removed it. So check your web.xml very carefully and reverse all recent changes to it - if it makes it work, just correct the config errors you just made