# Tomcat deployment issues

Tags: tomcat7

I deployed my war file in tomcat server but it is not showing on the webapps folder. I get this error

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException:ContainerBase.addChild: start:org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923759/tomcat-failing-to-deploy-war

Comment: Thank you i had a problem loading the main Class