# Azure Websites 404 Shutdown

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I seem to be seeing an issue with Azure Websites here that I have my website configured to stay up and I have not changed anything since deployment, but when accessing the site, there is now a 404 error.

Why would this happen if I haven't changed anything at all? 
This is highly unpredictable, how can I make sure this stays up?

EDIT:

In the Catalina log I saw the following, but not sure what this is indicating:

```
24-Jun-2017 01:24:27.421 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\axpertws.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/axpertws]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Logging in, restarting the service seemed to get it up again.  But I am not very confident it will stay up or for how long...anyone else have Azure reliability issues ?

Comment: There's probably a bug in your application that is causing the server to crash. It usually restarts automatically but takes a while every time. Enable diagnostic logs to get a better view of what's happening.

Comment: reading this it has nothing to do with azure, fix your code

Comment: so the web app is not live yet so nothing should be happening and i see the above error with IllegalStateException.   It would be helpful if you could point me in the direction to fix the code.  Catalina logs are only showing the above.

Comment: @fobius Could you make the war file works on your local tomcat? Please inspect it first.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes it works fine, I can deploy it fine locally and on Azure.  The problem is that when going back to check the Azure deployment later, it turned into a 404 page.

Comment: Had the same problem yesterday, after the app being live for months.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the first line indicates a problem with the archive.

> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web
>   application archive D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\axpertws.war

This definitely looks like a problem with your archive. See this thread for reference: [Tomcat failing to deploy .war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923759/tomcat-failing-to-deploy-war)